# Count how many times replay a audio - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a work to do for school and I need to do a game where it shows how many times a audio was played. I really don't know how to do that, I tried this code from the internet and I tried with a video but it says

> "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" `

```js
var iterations = 1;

document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function() {

  if (iterations < 5) {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
    iterations++;
    document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" id="myVideo" controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: In your code i can't see any `.innerHTML`.

Comment: The code is trying to display the current iteration. Add this to your HTML: `<p>Iteration: <span id="iteration"></span></p>`.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my mistake is innertext

Comment: where is the element with id of 'iteration'?

Comment: It still says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at"

Comment: I wrote in the code but It didn't show, it's the same Chris said

Comment: Inserting the div fixes the code, which makes the question pointless. If this is solved, just delete the question.

Comment: The thing is, this works here but not in my computer

Answer (score 1):

There was no element to update with the variable iterations

Make sure the JavaScript fires after the creation of the 'iteration' element in the DOM or you will get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
>       at ...

```js
 // set iteration to 1
 var iterations = 1;

 document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;
          
      myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {

      if (iterations < 5) {

           this.currentTime = 0;
           this.play();
           iterations ++;

           document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

       }

}, false);
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" id="myVideo" controls>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
<p>Iteration: <span id="iteration"></span></p>
```

Comment: I used that but it still says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
I don't know why

Comment: I don't know why it works here and not in my computer

Comment: Where have you added the JavaScript?

Comment: In the head is like <head><script></script></head> right?

Comment: Yeah, it was that xD

Comment: the JavaScript needs to fire after the creation of the element 'iteration' i have updated the answer above to include this.